# return value of fnmatch query python

Tags: python, filenames

All,
I have bunch of files and I want to extract files of form 
*_10_C*.xlsx, *_23_C*.xlsx,.. so on
I am using the following snippet to store these files

```
Pattern_Meas = '*_*_C*.xlsx', 
for name in LIV_files:
    if(fnmatch.fnmatchcase(name, Pattern_Meas)):
            fname_Temp_LI_list.append(name)
    else: fname_Temp_VI_list.append(name)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to extract the value of "*" in *_C, as to get output as 10, 23 etc. One way maybe using rsplit after I get the files but was wondering if there was something more efficient, like doing it in the same filename

Comment: The `fnmatch` module works by translating the pattern to a regular expression, and then using the `re` module to match that expression - in fact, you can get the regex it uses via `fnmatch.translate(Pattern_Meas)`.  If you wrote the regex yourself, you could put in a capturing group to extract part of the filename - `r"^_(.*)_C\.xlsx$"` perhaps

Comment: Thanks Jason, I am new to python and am trying the combinations for re. The one u suggest didnt quite do the trick

Comment: print(re.search('.*_(.*?)_c', a).group(1)) seems to do it. Although not sure why :) re is still strange to me